# Python list.append(another_list) is just repeating another_list again and again

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, deep-learning, pytorch

I am writing a program which goes through a loop.
In the loop body it make a Python list name value and append this value to another global list values
But i am having a issue that after using

values.append(value)

but it append the value to every element of values

```
# values
[['closed_eye_0003.jpg_face_2.jpg', 0]]
# value
['closed_eye_0007.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]
# after appending the value to values the output is 
[['closed_eye_0007.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0], ['closed_eye_0007.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]]
```

The Code is

```
import face_recognition
values = list()
value = list()
root_dir = '/content/dataset_facialImages_300/test/CloseFace'
isOpen = 0
for img_name in imgs_names:
  img_file = root_dir + '/' + img_name
  # Load the jpg file into a numpy array
  image = face_recognition.load_image_file(img_file)

  # Find all facial features in all the faces in the image
  face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)
  if len(face_landmarks_list):
    # print(len(face_landmarks_list))
    # print(img_name)
    first_face = face_landmarks_list[0]

    left_eye = first_face['left_eye']
    right_eye = first_face['right_eye']

    value.clear()
    value.append(img_name)
    value.append(isOpen)
    # for i in right_eye:
    #   value.append(i[0])
    #   value.append(i[1])
    print(value)
    # values.insert( len(values), value)
    values.append(value)
    print(values)
  # print( (len(values) / len(imgs_names)) * 100 )
```

The Output is

```
['closed_eye_0003.jpg_face_2.jpg', 0]
[['closed_eye_0003.jpg_face_2.jpg', 0]]
['closed_eye_0007.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]
[['closed_eye_0007.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0], ['closed_eye_0007.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]]
['closed_eye_0009.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]
[['closed_eye_0009.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0], ['closed_eye_0009.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0], ['closed_eye_0009.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]]
['closed_eye_0012.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]
[['closed_eye_0012.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0], ['closed_eye_0012.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0], ['closed_eye_0012.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0], ['closed_eye_0012.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]]
```

If i use

```
values.extend(value)
```

it does not repeat

if i use

```
values.insert( len(values), value)
```

the output is same

The output should be

```
['closed_eye_0003.jpg_face_2.jpg', 0]
[['closed_eye_0003.jpg_face_2.jpg', 0]]
['closed_eye_0007.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]
[['closed_eye_0003.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0], ['closed_eye_0007.jpg_face_1.jpg', 0]]
```

Comment: I didn't go through the entire code but can you try this ? `values.append([value])`

Comment: no the repetition is still happening

Comment: You keep appending the **same list** so of course it has the same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `value = list()` inside the loop instead of clearing it.

If you print `value` and `values` after clearing `value`, you would understand what's going on.

Comment: i did it i print value and values after clearing the value value.clear(). it clears both  value and values the output is   
value: []   
values: [[], [], []]    
what can be the reason

Comment: @Ahwar Please clarify what you mean, and possibly include it as a small edit/update to your post.

Comment: @Ahwar: Basically when all `value` to `values`, it is just adding a reference of `value`, and not a separate copy.  Since you are always adding the same variable `value`, it always adds the same reference to the list. So essentially, all the elements in `values` point to the same variable `value`. Does that help?